# How to position a div only over another div

Tags: html, css

I want to position one div absolute in the center of the screen and make it float in front of another div. But when the user scrolls down and the div reaches the footer it should stop floating and be placed just above of the footer. Here is some example code that doesnt work:

```css
.main {
background: blue;
height: 2000px;
}
.footer {
background: red;
height: 400px;
}
.float {
background: green;
position:fixed;
height: 30px;
width: 100px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main</div>
<div class="float">Button</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Here are some images about how i would expect the element to react:

just over the main:
[image]

the desired state when it reaches the footer:
[image]

A solution using pure css would be prefered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed`.

`position: sticky`:

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.

`position: fixed`:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its initial containing block, which is the viewport in the case of visual media. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

#### Check following example:

```css
.main {
background: blue;
height: 2000px;
}
.footer {
background: red;
height: 400px;
}
.float {
background: green;
position: sticky;
height: 30px;
width: 100px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main</div>
<div class="float">Button</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```